# What's the difference between WebSocket fragmentation and TCP fragmentation?

Tags: tcp, websocket, protocols, network-protocols

I'm reading about Websocket and I see that protocol have a data fragmentation (frames), a WebSocket message is composed of one or more frames, but it's not what TCP (fragmentation of data) do? I'm confused.

Comment: Websocket is a tcp connection  b/w two web servers

Comment: I want to know if data fragmentation is a feature of the TCP or Websocket protocol or both have but differently.

Comment: Upto my understanding. Websocket is a communication protocol supported natively by your browser and server. Websocket internally can use any protocol to communicate but tcp is recommended/preferred as per standard. So once it use tcp. There should not be any difference in fragmentation b/w the both

Comment: Fragmentation is data fragmentation

Comment: So why is it specified? (in the Websocket specification)

Comment: Please correct your question with the link where you find that fragmentation.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5

Comment: So what part of your question is not snswered by section 5.4?

Answer (score 7):

Fragmentation in the context of data transfer just means splitting the original data into smaller parts for transfer and combining these fragments later (for example at the recipients side) again to recreate the original data.

Fragmentation is often done if the underlying layer cannot handle larger messages or if larger messages will result in performance problems. Such problems might be  because it is more expensive if one large message is lost and need to be repeated instead of only a small fragment. Or it can be a performance problem if the transfer of one large message would block the delivery of smaller messages. In this case it is useful to split the large message into fragments and deliver these message fragments together with the other messages so that these don't have to wait for delivery until the large message is done.

Fragmentation of messages in WebSockets is just one of the many types of fragmentation which exist at various layers at the data transport, like:

- IP messages can be fragmented at the sender or some middlebox and get reassembled at the end.
- TCP is a data stream. The various parts of the stream are transferred in different IP packets and get reassembled in the correct order at the recipient.
- Application layer protocols like HTTP can have fragments too, for example the chunked Transfer-Encoding mode within HTTP or the fragments in WebSockets.
- And at even higher layers there can be more fragments, like the spreading of a single large ZIP file into multiple parts onto floppy disks in former times or the accelerating of downloads by requesting different parts of the same file in parallel connections and combining these at the recipient.

Comment: First point is not strictly correct – IPv6 packets can be fragmented only by the sender.

Answer (score 7):

I love the detailed answer by Steffen Ullrich, but I wish to add a few specific details regarding the differences between raw TCP/IP and the added Websockets layer.

TCP/IP is a **stream protocol**, meaning the application receives the data as fragmented pieces **as data become available**, with no clear indication of the fragmented "packet boundaries" or the original (non-fragmented) data structure.

The Websocket protocol is a **message based protocol**, meaning that the application will only receive the full Websocket message **once all the fragmented pieces have arrived and put back together**.

As a very simplified example:

**TCP/IP**: if a 50 Mb file is sent using TCP, the application will probably receive a piece of the file at a time and it will need to piece the file back together (possibly saving each piece to a temporary disk storage).

**Websocket**: if a 50 Mb file is sent using the Websocket protocol, the application will receive the whole of the 50Mb in one message (and the storage of all of the data, memory or disk, will be dictated by the Websocket layer, not the application layer).

Note that the Websocket Protocol is an additional layer over the TCP/IP protocol, so data is streamed over TCP/IP and the Websocket layer puts the pieces back together before forwarding the original (whole) message).

Answer (score 4):

[5.4.  Fragmentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.4)

> A secondary use-case for fragmentation is for multiplexing, where it
> is not desirable for a large message on one logical channel to
> monopolize the output channel, so the multiplexing needs to be free
> to split the message into smaller fragments to better share the
> output channel.  (Note that the multiplexing extension is not
> described in this document.)

Even though it's listed as secondary reason, I'd say that't the primary reason for that fragmentation feature. Imagine, if you try to send first message with 1GB size and right away when you start sending it you also send second message with 1KB size. Framing allows applications to inject second message in between individual frames of the first message, this way receiver will not need to wait for 1GB to be transferred and will receive/handle 1KB second message right away.